WebView not showing pop up for OAuth in .Net MAUI mac os
I am using the Dropbox service, which offers Google and Apple login options. I am displaying the login page using a WebView. However, when I click on the Google or Apple login buttons, it doesn't open a pop-up to show available accounts, as it does in a browser. Is this an issue with the WebView? Any help would be appreciated.
Code snippet XAML
<WebView
 x:Class = "TessApp.WebView"
 xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
 xmlns:x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2002/xaml"
 HeightRequest="500"
 WidthRequest="500"
 Source = "https://www.dropbox.com/login"
 Navigating="OnNavigating"
 Navigated="OnNavigated" />

CS
private void OnNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    // Add your code to handle the Navigating event here
    Console.WriteLine($"Navigating to: {e.Url}");
}

private void OnNavigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    // Add your code to handle the Navigated event here
    Console.WriteLine($"Navigated to: {e.Url}");
}

Expected behavior:
Show a pop-up while clicking on Google or Apple auth buttons.
Note: It is working fine for WINDOWs.
